# Are there benefits of having SSO (single-sign-on) capability in an online community?

Tags: new-members

If you have a site with accounts and you have a community whether it's a forum, a discord server, etc are there any benefits of having SSO? I thought that it may encourage new users to sign up since it's just 1 click but it would also lead to low user retention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes!

For new users/members onboarding that requires the creation of accounts across multiple services or applications that support SSO, it can definitely be beneficial. Having one login to rule them all allows users to pick one set of credentials and only need to remember that set of credentials. If they use a password manager, that password manager only needs one entry for all of those shared accounts. SSO simplifies what could be a more confusing process of creating accounts with different credentials across multiple services/apps.

#### Concerns

You should consider a few concerns when asking new users to utilize single sign-on:

1. **Security** - Having one set of credentials to sign into multiple services means that if a user leaks those credentials or otherwise has their account hijacked, all services that use the same SSO credentials will be compromised. Consider implementing secondary security or recovery methods, and forcing moderator/admin-level users to use additional security measures on their accounts.
2. **Forgetting credentials** - A user who forgets their credentials will subsequently lose access to all services that their single account is on. This may completely lock them out of their connected community, such that they can't even ask for help from other members. Consider ensuring new users set up recovery methods for this eventuality!

#### Summary

SSO can be very beneficial to a community that uses connected services, but one should certainly consider security concerns when implementing it. Beyond that, users should find the use of SSO to be quite nice when getting started with your community!